# Cannot mount raspberry pi's sd card

Tags: ssh, sd-card, mount

My raspberry pi was working fine yesterday. Today, I could not ssh into it. I do not have an hdmi screen, so the first thing I tried was taking out the sd card and putting it in my computer. The `Disks` utility does not recognise the drive. `fdisk -l` looks more promising, but I am too scared to mount anything out of fear of making it worse.

Relevant part of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 8010 MB, 8010072064 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 244448 cylinders, total 15644672 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002c457

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            8192     3167968     1579888+   e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2         3170304    15579135     6204416   85  Linux extended
/dev/mmcblk0p3        15579136    15644671       32768   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p5         3178496     3301375       61440    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p6         3309568    15579135     6134784   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mmcblk0p1: 3898 MB, 3898605568 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 118976 cylinders, total 7614464 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002c457

          Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1p1            8192     3167968     1579888+   e  W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p1p2         3170304    15579135     6204416   85  Linux extended
/dev/mmcblk0p1p3        15579136    15644671       32768   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p1p5         3178496     3301375       61440    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p1p6         3309568    15579135     6134784   83  Linux
```

The model is raspberry pi B+ running raspbian. My computer is running Linux Mint 17.2.

Comment: What about the 3.5mm port? Surely you have a TV with RCA connections, no?

Comment: Nope. In university residence. No tv here.

Comment: If you don't have an HDMI capable monitor, may I ask how you went through the initial setup in the first place?

Comment: Another member of my robotics team set it up.

Comment: Got ya. Is it possible the Pi isn't connecting to the network or has a different IP?

Comment: Nope eurobot. And I doubt it. My router does not show it and anyway when it was working I set up dhcp reservation for the mac address.

Comment: Hmm. Well, you wouldn't happen to have a console cable? Like this: https://www.adafruit.com/products/954

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Mostly I'm looking for a way to mount the sd card without making anything worse.

Comment: Well, according to this, you can just mount it normally: http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/mounting-raspberry-pis-ext4-sd

Comment: Which partition would it be? In the article it said `/dev/sda1` but as you can see I don't have that. Mine are more like `/dev/mmcblk0p1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37875/discussion-between-android-dev-and-marcel).